# jQuery trigger not firing event the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

jQuery's trigger() function is not behaving as I expect when I use it from the dev console in Chrome /Firefox, but strangely it seems to work fine in IE.

Here's a simple example:

```js
function test() {
  $("body").on("focus", ".text-input", function(e) {
    console.log("focus")
  })
  $(".text-input").trigger("focus")
  $(".text-input").trigger("focus")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="text-input" />
<button onclick="test()">Test</button>
```

If I just open it and click the button, I see 2 "focus" printed in the console, in all 3 browsers, as expected.

If instead, I reload the page and execute test() from the console, I still see 2 "focus" in IE, but Chrome and Firefox print only one. Any further execution of test() prints two focus in all browsers.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Browser versions:
Chrome 67.0.3396.99
Fireox 57.0.4
IE 11

Comment: This sounds like an X/Y question. Is there a specific reason you need this, rather odd, behaviour to work

Comment: Obviously this is just a proof of concept. I first noticed this at work, our text inputs have labels that change depending on the field being empty or not. During testing, executing some functions from the console wasn't changing their state as expected... but executing a second time did.